# How to get display name "email"?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

```
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZBMv.png
this image show database username is null, I want to set name from email user registered/logined
```

```
public void memperbaruiQuest() {

        String uid = getUid();  // this is FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()

        final DatabaseReference mScore = mdatabase.child(Aktivitas).child(String.valueOf(uid));
        DatabaseReference muser = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(String.valueOf(uid)).child("User name");
        muser.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                String name = String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.getValue());

                mScore.child("username").setValue(name); //this is null?
```

can i get the email or name after login?
what I must doing for the username no null in firebase? thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once the user is logged in you can do this to get the email and name.

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
String name = user.getDisplayName();
String email = user.getEmail();
```

After, you can update those in your firebase database.Make sure you access the right nodes though.

Answer (score 0):

i solve that ...

```
public void memperbaruiQuest() {

    String uid = getUid();
    final DatabaseReference mScore = mdatabase.child(Aktivitas).child(String.valueOf(uid));
    DatabaseReference muser = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(Aktivitas).child(uid);

    final String user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getEmail(); // just add this

    muser.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {


            String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.getValue());
            mScore.child("username").setValue(user); //and set on here

        }
```

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/i9LZs.png

this is a picture I mean hehe
```